# same name of a variable and a function ( ls ) in R

Tags: r

By accident I created a variable called ls which I have spotted using ls(). So there exist a function ls() and a variable with the identical name. I do not know what kind of variable it is and don't know the content because all attempts failed to access the variable.

```
ls
```

returned the body of the ls() function.

```
get("ls")
```

returned Error in get(ls) : invalid first argument

```
get("ls", mode="numeric")
```

object 'ls' of mode 'numeric' was not found

```
get("ls", mode=!"function")
```

is not a valid argument.
So how can I access the variable? I tried also class(ls) and str(ls) but all is referring to ls as a function.

I can't find the right question to this. But I am sure I have read about that before. So I am sorry if that is a duplicate post. Help and a link would be appreciated.

EDIT: the output of `dput(ls()[grep("^ls$", ls())])` is:

```
"ls"
```

EDIT: the output of `dput(ls())` is:

```
c("bplo.anno", "c", "combinations.formula", "combo.form", "df", "df.group.unique", "df.test", "dir.work", "form.compl", "fun.boot.lm.stepAIC.4", "fun.boot.lm.stepAIC.5", "fun.CoerceListOfVectorToMatrix", "fun.data.preparation", "fun.dcor.DataFrame", "fun.expand.complete.interaction", "fun.g.ellipse.orig", "fun.K_fold", "fun.lappend", "fun.lm.subset", "fun.lm_AIC", "fun.lst.powerset", "fun.MaxToMinModel.adjrsq", "fun.MaxToMinModel.rsq", "fun.plot.circle", "fun.results", "fun.rs.dcor", "fun.vectorcoerce", "group", "height", "i", "j", "k", "ls", "ls.boot", "ls1", "lst.boot.result", "oldwd", "regressor.names", "response.name", "result.df", "rs.dcor", "source.filename", "tbl.bt", "tbl.nm")
```

Comment: What does `str(ls)` give you?

Comment: str(ls) returns function (name, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), all.names = FALSE, 
    pattern)

Comment: I can't replicate this, are you sure the variable `ls` exists? You could try `.GlobalEnv$ls` but I think that if it does exist in your global environment you should simply be able to access it with `ls`.

Comment: Not sure. since I cant remember that I created it. I just saw it in ls(). So I assume it exists an object with the name ls.

Comment: You have a variable `ls1` - are you getting confused?

Comment: ls1 and ls. dput(ls()[grep("^ls$", ls())]) gives me ls.

Comment: @Sebastian Sorry, my reading skills are at fault. I missed `ls` :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you have copied the function `ls()`, i.e.

```
ls = ls
```

This reproduces your "problems" So

```
get("ls")
```

returns a function. You get the same error messages:

```
R> get("ls", mode="numeric")
Error in get("ls", mode = "numeric") : 
  object 'ls' of mode 'numeric' was not found
R> get("ls", mode=!"function")
Error in !"function" : invalid argument type
```

and the `dput` gives the same result:

```
R> dput(ls()[grep("^ls$", ls())]) 
"ls"
```

Comment: Yep. You are right. I must have copied it. I was not aware of that possibility. That explains it.